# Xamarin.Forms - OnStop(), OnExit(), OnClose()

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app and I need to know when the app gets Stopped, Closed, Exited, whatever interrupts it, in order to stop some services such as WebSocket. How can I get 'access' to those events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the following in a small example. (Tested it on UWP and works, the *OnSleep()* is called, when i close the App). The *OnSleep()* Method which can be overridden in the App.xaml.cs is the Method you are looking for.

The [Xamarin Application LifeCycle](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/app-lifecycle/) offers some methods for your needs.

> ```
> OnStart - Called when the application starts.
>
> OnSleep - Called each time the application goes to the background.
>
> OnResume - Called when the application is resumed, after being sent to the background.
> ```
>
> Note that **there is no method for application termination**. Under normal
>   circumstances (ie. not a crash) application termination will happen
>   from the OnSleep state, without any additional notifications to your
>   code.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                MainPage = new MainPage();
            else
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart() {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnStart");
        }
        protected override void OnSleep() {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnSleep");
        }
        protected override void OnResume() {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnResume");
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

According to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58002/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-catch-all-unhandled-exceptions-on-xamarin-forms) you have to catch unhandled exceptions in the native code. That makes it a lil complicated to shutdown your services.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        private void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs unhandledExceptionEventArgs) {
            //crashed by exception
        }
    }
```

Further Reading on Unhandled Exceptions: [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/System.AppDomain.UnhandledException/)

Comment: I tried it works :) However, how do you handle when the app crash or you click the square VS2017 `stop debugging`. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Added the the event for unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Added another event handler - that should be enough to catch nearly every exit/crash that could occur

Comment: `The AppDomain doesn't exist in the current context`

Comment: Oh - true gimme a second to check that

Comment: I fear you cannot catch them in the same place

Comment: That would be so usefull, because for le that works with sockets, everytime a crash happens or you stop debugging, the socket doesn't get close... :(